# handle protected route logic

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm creating a protected route for my react project but context values and redux reducers data are not persistent. So what is the optimal way to set, for example `isVerified` to `true` if the user is logged. If `isVerified === true` go to homepage else redirect to login, `isVerified` needs to be mutated every change in route or refresh, because context or redux data is not persistent.

Do I need to create a separate backend api for just checking the token coming from the client side? then I will add a useEffect in the main `App.tsx`, something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    /*make api call, and pass the token stored in the localStorage. If 
    verified success then: */
    setIsVerified(true)
}, [])
```

Then I can use the `isVerified` to my protected route

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Middleware component wrapping both, Protected and Non-protected components routes. And inside of each just check if the user is logged, then render conditionally.

This is usually how I implemented,

Protected:

```js
// AuthRoute.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";


export const AuthRoute = ({ exact = false, path, component }) => {
  const [isVerified, setIsVerified] = useState(false);

  const checkLoginSession = () => {
  // Write your verifying logic here
    const loggedUser = window.localStorage.getItem("accessToken") || "";
    return loggedUser !== "" ? true : false;
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      const sessionState = await checkLoginSession();
      return setIsVerified(sessionState);
    })();
  }, []);

  return isVerified ? (
    <Route exact={exact} path={path} component={component} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to={"/login"} />
  );
};
```

Non-protected:

```js
import React from "react";

import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const NAuthRoute = ({ exact = false, path, component }) => {
  const [isVerified, setIsVerified] = useState(false);

  const checkLoginSession = () => {
 // Write your verifying logic here
    const loggedUser = window.localStorage.getItem("accessToken") || "";
    return loggedUser !== "" ? true : false;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      const sessionState = await checkLoginSession();
      return setIsVerified(sessionState);
    })();
  }, []);

  return isVerified ? 
     <Redirect to={"/"} /> 
     : <Route exact={exact} path={path} component={component} />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this process and so far it is the most helpful way to make a route protected.

ProtectedRoute.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    const isSessionAuth = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest} 
            render={props => {
                if(isSessionAuth)
                {
                    return (<Component {...props}/>);
                }else{
                    return <Redirect to={
                        {
                            pathname: "/",
                            state: {
                                from: props.location
                            }
                        }
                    }/>
                }
            }
        }/>
    );
};
```

In the place where you are defining routes you can use this like this.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import { ProtectedRoute } from './ProtectedRoute.js';

import SignUp from "./pages/SignUp";
import SignIn from "./pages/SignIn";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound";

const Routes = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
            <ProtectedRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Routes;
```